# Why isn't the order of a sequence kept in nim when deleting an element?

Tags: sequence, nim-lang

I am trying out nim and struggling with a strange behaviour while working with sequences.

If i run this code:

```
var
    hobbies = @["Coding", "Creating", "Sports"]

echo hobbies

hobbies.add("Nature")
echo hobbies

hobbies.del(0)
echo hobbies
```

I would expect this output, because I thought its working like a queue:

```
@["Coding", "Creating", "Sports"]
@["Coding", "Creating", "Sports", "Nature"]
@["Creating", "Sports", "Nature"]
```

but insted i get this:

```
@["Coding", "Creating", "Sports"]
@["Coding", "Creating", "Sports", "Nature"]
@["Nature", "Creating", "Sports"]
```

After deleting via index `.del(0)` The value `"Nature"` is switching to index 0.

Shouldn't the order be kept?

Version:

```
Nim Compiler Version 1.6.14 [Linux: amd64]
Compiled at 2023-06-29
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`del` operation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#del%2Cseq%5BT%5D%2CNatural) swaps the last items with the item being removed and then pops it. Has constant complexity.

If you want to preserve order of elements then you'll need to use [`delete` operation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#delete%2Cseq%5BT%5D%2CNatural) that will shift index of each item after the item being removed by 1. This operation has linear complexity proportional to the size of the sequence.